# Displaying a loading modal while fetching data in another modal

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-modal

I have a modal in my app in which data is being fetched and display called `<MyModal/>`. Inside it I have another single modal called `<InfoModal/>` (nested) which will be shown on top of the previous one for two purposes: displaying a "Loading..." component while the data is being fetched or displaying a prompt with whatever error the API returned  while attempting to fetch the data. Sort of a shapeshifting modal, depending on whether we're in a loading state or an error state.

***Why  am I choosing this approach:*** On iOS you can't show a modal on top of another one simultaneously unless they're nested just like that.

**What is the problem with the code below:**

Case A: If the API returns an error, **on Android** the loading prompt is shown briefly and then the error modal appears (**this is the intended behaviour**). On iOS, it skips the loading modal and it "shapeshifts" directly into the error displaying one.

Case B: If the API returns no error, the loading modal remains stuck and never closes (on both **iOS** and **Android**)

***What am I doing wrong?***

```
type Props = {
  isMyModalVisible: boolean // This is the visibility state of <MyModal/> controlled by a state residing in the screeen containing <MyModal/>
}

const MyModal = ({ isMyModalVisible }: Props) => {


  const [dataFetchedFromAPI, setDataFetchedFromAPI] = useState<any>(null); // This is the data that will be displayed inside <MyModal/>
  const [isInfoModalVisible, setIsInfoModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [infoModalType, setInfoModalType] = useState<"Error" | "Loading | null">(null); // State which controls if the 2nd modal is in "Loading" shape or "Error displaying shape"
  const [infoModalMessage, setInfoModalMessage] = useState(""); // The message to be displayed in the 2nd modal (if it's in "Error" shape)

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetching some data from API
    fetchDataFromAPI();
  }, [])

  const fetchDataFromAPI = async () => {
    // When the call starts, we're setting the state of the 2nd modal in "Loading" shape and its visibility to "true"
    setInfoModalType("Loading")
    setIsInfoModalVisible(true)

    dataFetchingMethod()
      .then((response: any) => {
        setDataFetchedFromAPI(response)
      })
      .catch(async (error) => {

        // In case we get an error, we set the visibility of 2nd modal to true, set it into "Error" shape and retain in a state variable the error message received from API
        setInfoModalType("Eroare")
        setInfoModalMessage(error.message)
        setIsInfoModalVisible(true);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        // After the API call is done, in case the 2nd modal was in "Loading" shape, close it
        if (infoModalType === "Loading") {
          setInfoModalType("")
          setIsInfoModalVisible(false)
        }
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={isMyModalVisible}>

        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={isInfoModalVisible}>
          {
            infoModalType === "Loading"
              ?
              <View>
                {/*.....CODE FOR DISPLAYING LOADING MODAL....*/}
              </View>
              :
              <View>
                {/*.....CODE FOR DISPLAYING ERROR MODAL....*/}
              </View>

          }
        </Modal>
        <View>
          {/*....Code for <MyModal where the data fetched from the API is displayed/> */}
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyModal
```